# Host multiple website using nginx on the same IP

Tags: networking, domain, nginx

I've set up a Raspberry Pi to act as web server, so I've installed **nginx** with php5 and I bought **two domains**:

1. domain1.co.uk
2. Domain2.it

I have a static IP which is linked to these two domains, so if I type one or the other I get the same example web page that I wrote.

How could I do to set a directory for a domain and another for the other domain?

Comment: I like that you're using NGINX :) You are looking to implement something called virtual hosting. This has been available with Apache since 1995 I believe so it would be rather silly if NGINX did not support it lol. I didn't read the whole thing but here is some history reading: http://httpd.apache.org/ABOUT_APACHE.html

Comment: Yes, that's helpful. Thank you. That wasn't listed in related question, maybe the title was too different from mine.

Comment: You're welcome and good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the server section of the config you can specfify the server_name and the related root, so e.g. in /mnt/web/nginx/conf.d/ you create 2 .conf files with

e.g.

```
server {
  server_name domain1.co.uk; 
  root /mnt/web/sites/dom1site;
  access_log /var/log/nginx/domain1.co.uk.access_log;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/domain1.co.uk.error_log;
  include /etc/nginx/global/restrictions.conf;
  include /etc/nginx/global/wordpress.conf;
}
```

and

```
server {
  server_name Domain2.it;
  root /mnt/web/sites/dom2site;
  access_log /var/log/nginx/domain2.it.access_log;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/domain2.it.error_log;
  include /etc/nginx/global/restrictions.conf;
  include /etc/nginx/global/wikipedia.conf;
}
```

here is a handy link to configuration help: http://wiki.nginx.org/Configuration

So... in your main nginx.conf you specify the http {} where you can reference a directory where you have all the configs for the individual site configs (probably the handiest).

example (!) of nginx.conf:

```
user rasp-user rasp-user;
worker_processes  1;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid       /var/run/nginx.pid;
events {    
    worker_connections  1024;
}
http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log main;        
    tcp_nopush off;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    sendfile        on;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    client_body_timeout   10;
    client_header_timeout 10;
    keepalive_timeout     15;
    send_timeout          10;
    client_body_buffer_size 8K;
    client_header_buffer_size 1k;
    client_max_body_size 20m;
    large_client_header_buffers 2 1k;
    gzip             on;
    gzip_comp_level  2;
    gzip_min_length  1000;
    gzip_proxied     expired no-cache no-store private auth;
    gzip_types       text/plain application/xml;
    gzip_disable     "MSIE [1-6]\.";
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    upstream php {
       #server unix:/tmp/php-fpm.sock;
       server 127.0.0.1:9000;
    }
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /mnt/web/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

Comment: I just throw the nodes into the main file, but same result.

Comment: you don't use default in sites-available?